# Nginx virtual host servername, root

Tags: nginx, php, freebsd, php-fpm, php5

I installed `nginx-1.6.2,2` on `FreeBSD-9.2-RELEASE-p5` and here is my configuration:

```
# tail -2 nginx.conf
    include _includes/*.conf;
}
# cat _includes/XXX.conf 
server {
    server_name XXX;
    root    /home/user/XXX/;
    index   index.php;
    include _includes/_location-php.include;
}
# cat _includes/_location-php.include 
location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
# tail -1 /var/log/nginx-error.log 
2014/11/17 11:45:59 [error] 82950#0: *6 open() "/usr/local/www/nginx/admin.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: XX.XX.XX.XX, server: localhost, request: "GET /admin.php HTTP/1.1", host: "XXX"
#
```

There is another `root` that's pointed to `/usr/local/www/nginx` in another server block with `server_name localhost` (default configuration - http://pastebin.com/caRJM20f)

Why is it taking that over my `root` as I specified for another `server_name`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `listen [IP:]80;` inside of the `server` section in your `_includes/XXX.conf` file.